# HTTPS for Laravel Rest-API endpoints

Tags: laravel, ssl, laravel-5.6

Hi i am in need of adding an SSL certificate for our web application, currently our front end (VUE.JS SPA Application) has SSL certification, due to this all my Laravel API endpoints are being rejected. Can any one point out any tutorials on how to convert my laravel endpoints from HTTP to HTTPS.

the console message i recieve is,

> The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ip/example-api/public/api/banner'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I am using CertBot to create a SSL certificate from letsEncrypt.

thanks.

Comment: what error are u getting , please add

Comment: in `config/session.php` set `'http_only' => false,`

Comment: the front end is Vue.js @ShaieIndra

Answer (score 0):

If your front-end is HTTPS, any client-side calls to your backend must be, as well. You will need to install and configure an SSL certificate on the server containing your Laravel instance.

Comment: (The *specifics* of installing an SSL certificate will vary based on OS and webserver. Google up a Let's Encrypt tutorial for your infrastructure; it'll take about 20 minutes.)

Comment: i checked some most of them require a conf file to add the SSL certification. my laravel backend doesn't have a conf file

Comment: Sure it does. If you're on shared hosting you may not have direct *access* to it and need to go through your host to set up an SSL cert, but *somewhere* there's a webserver configuration to manage.

Comment: I am using a digitalocean droplet with ubuntu 16.04. i checked the /etc/apache2/sites-available there was no conf files, where else should i look,

Comment: There's likely to be a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file or something along those lines. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04.

Comment: will editting that file affect any other web sites hosted in this droplet.

Comment: Maybe! You should understand its contents before you edit them. It's **your** file - I don't know what modifications you made to it when you set up the server.

Comment: k ill check it out Thanks for the help

Comment: I am using certbot to add ssl certification when i ran `sudo certbot --apache certonly` it ask to select which domain name to add to, and default.conf is not in the list, is there any method to add this to the .htaccess file in laravel project